# EXTJS 4.2 - How to Dynamically Change a Grid Row's Action Icon Tooltip?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have a grid that displays a bunch of records.  I have an action column in the grid that displays various buttons users can click on to perform various actions on each individual record.

One of these buttons i want to dynamically change the tooltip for depending on the record type.  I have 2 types, activity and lead. If the record is an activity, I want the button to show an 'Close Activity' tooltip when the cursor hovers over it.  If the record is a lead, I want the button to show an 'Accept Lead' tooltip when the cursor hovers over it.

Right now I have a getClass method that is already checking other things to dynamically change the button image, for example if it's a lead/activity that's already closed, it would display a red check mark, and if it's not closed, it would display a green check mark.  I just want a method to change the tooltip as well.  Here is my current code for the getClass method.

```
getClass: function(v, meta, rec) {
    if( 'Y' === rec.get('closed_f') ) {
        return 'x-icon-complete-red';
    } else {
        return 'x-icon-complete-green';
    }
}
```

How do I go about changing the tooltip as well?  I've already tried this.tooltip = '[text]', this.setTooltip('[text]').  I noticed that in the above code context, 'this' is actually the grid object, not the button object, so it obviously wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch tooltips depending on records data, the `getTip` function (like `getClass`) is the way to go... (normally). Since `getTip` doesn't work for everyone in Ext 4.2, you can add a dynamic tooltip in the getClass function like this if `getTip` isn't working:

```
getClass: function(v, meta, rec) {
    if( 'Y' === rec.get('closed_f') ) {
        this.items[0].tooltip = 'Your custom tooltip';
        return 'x-icon-complete-red';
    } else {
        return 'x-icon-complete-green';
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the index in `this.items[0]` is the index of the button in the actioncolumn. If your button is the second one, you have to set `1` instead of `0` and so on...

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action-cfg-getTip

Solution: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2e7k

Comment: Thanks Tyr, I want to try that, however 'this' in my code refers to the grid, not the actual button object. :(

Comment: `this` is referred to the `actioncolumn` and `items` contains the buttons.

Comment: Do you happen to know if 'this' is the grid object, how would I go about targetting the action column so i can access its items?

Comment: Are you sure about `this` is the grid object? Try `console.info(this.getXType())`. Here is a functional demo https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2e7k

Comment: Yes, 'this' is the grid object when it reaches that point in the getClass function.

Comment: Interesting. In this case you can use `this.down('actioncolumn').items[0]` instead of `this.items[0]`

Comment: An additional note.  I see the button info under second item in the this.actions array, so when I do this.actions[1].tooltip = 'Accept Lead' it will indeed change the button tooltip.  However, when I have 2 items, an activity and a lead, it somehow ends up making the tooltip for the button on the activity say 'Accept Lead' and the tooltip for the button on the lead say 'Close Activity', the exact opposite of what I want it to do.

Comment: That's extremely odd to me because I put a breakpoint at the beginning of my logic and walked through each line thereafter and it seems to run correctly, just for some reason the tooltips on the buttons are flipped.  I don't even know what would happen if I had 2 activities and 1 lead, or vice versa on the grid

Comment: using this.down('actionclolumn').items[1] instead of this.actions[1] has the same behavior as what I described in my previous 2 comments.  I'm so baffled.

Comment: I just forced it to have 2 activities and 1 lead in the grid.  The order in which the records are shown in the grid is activity 1, lead, activity 2.  Activity 2's button tooltip shows 'Accept Lead' while activity 1 and lead both show 'Close Activity' for tooltips.  For the case in my previous comments where it is showing activity and a lead, the activity shows 'Accept Lead' for the tooltip while for the lead it shows 'Close Activity'

Comment: Another behavior I noticed in the case with 3 records showing on the grid is if I sort the records by a certain column, whatever record is last in the list will have the 'Accept Lead' tooltip, leading me to believe the grid is handling these tooltips independently from the actual individual records.

Comment: I think it's copying the button config from the previous row to the next one which results in this behavior. Here is a fiddle how you can set the tooltip in the renderer config for the action column. I hope this helps: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2e7k

Comment: Thanks Tyr so much for all your help with this!  That last example you gave pointed me in the right direction and I finally got it to work!  The solution for my specific problem was very similar to your solution, with some extra workarounds because the project I'm working on uses a framework built on top of the extjs framework so I had to do some overriding of the renderer function.